# "Meta-objects"?

Tags: php, oop

I want to do something like this:

```
class StrangeClass {

    public function somethingLikeAMethod($var) {
        /* ... */
    }

    public function awesomeTest() {
        /* ... */
    }

}

$obj = new StrangeClass;
$ex1 = $obj->somethingLikeAMethod(1);

$ex2 = $obj->somethingLikeAMethod(2);

$ex1 -> awesomeTest(); // This will output "1"
$ex2 -> awesomeTest(); // This will output "2"
```

Other words, I want that object change its behavior.

In Lua language I can make this with 'metatables', but I doesn't know how to make this in OO-PHP.
Thank you.

### Added:

I did something like this in Lua:

```
local query = Database.query(...) -- now this variable has a query id
local query2 = Database.query(...) -- this is a other query id

local result = query.fetchAssoc() -- read below
local result2 = query.fetchAssoc() -- I called the same object with same method twice, but it will return other results
```

### Added #2:

What I want to do:

```
$db = new Database();

$firstResult = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `table`')->fetch_assoc();
$firstExample = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '1'");
$secondExample = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '2'");

$secondResult = $firstExample -> fetch_assoc();
$thirdResult = $secondExample -> fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: That looks an awful lot like a setter/getter to me, which I imagine is not what you are asking. Please elaborate.

Comment: Hmm, I doesn't know hot to explain this better. I'll think and I'll edit the question.

Comment: So StrangeClass is really some species of factory?

Comment: are you looking for some sort of queue system whereby you can stack up a bunch of queries and then run them in order?

Comment: Prisoner, yes, I want use this in Database class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

God knows why you want it, but this will work for you:

```
class StrangeClass {

    public function somethingLikeAMethod($var) {
        $this->test_var = $var;
        return clone $this;
    }

    public function awesomeTest() {
        echo $this->test_var;
    }

}

$obj = new StrangeClass;
$ex1 = $obj->somethingLikeAMethod(1);

$ex2 = $obj->somethingLikeAMethod(2);

$ex1->awesomeTest(); // This will output "1"
$ex2->awesomeTest(); // This will output "2"
```

---

Edit: If you're looking for a queuing system, you can push each query into an array, something like:

```
class StrangeClass {

    private $queries = array();

    public function somethingLikeAMethod($var) {
        $this->queries[] = $var;
        return $this;
    }

    public function awesomeTest() {
        if(count($this->queries) === 0){
            echo 'no queries left';
        }
        echo $this->queries[0];
        array_splice($this->queries,0,1);
    }

}

$obj = new StrangeClass;
$ex1 = $obj->somethingLikeAMethod("select * from hello");
$ex2 = $obj->somethingLikeAMethod("select * from me");
$ex2 = $obj->somethingLikeAMethod("select * from you");
$ex2 = $obj->somethingLikeAMethod("select * from my_friend");

$ex1->awesomeTest();
$ex2->awesomeTest();
$ex2->awesomeTest();
$ex2->awesomeTest();
$ex2->awesomeTest();
```

Comment: Wow, I read your edit and I understood, that your variant better than my current architecture. Thank you very much!